# Trying to do some asynchronous processing in django on heroku using Redis Queue

Tags: django, heroku, redis, worker

I am trying to upload bigger files to s3 asynchronously.I have followed documentaion from http://python-rq.org/ . Worker is running but it is not doing doing the job.

views.py

```
 def youmaterial(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        newdoc = Youmaterial(docfile = request.FILES['file'],user=request.user)
        newdoc.save()
        msg='dee'
            # Redirect to the document list after POST
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': msg}))

    else:
        form1 = DocumentForm()
    return render(request,'mat_upload.html',{'form':form1})

def create_job():
    redis_conn = Redis()
    q = Queue(connection=redis_conn)  # no args implies the default queue

# Delay execution of count_words_at_url('http://nvie.com')
    job = q.enqueue(youmaterial, 'http://heroku.com')
```

worker.py

```
import os
import urlparse
from redis import Redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL')
if not redis_url:
    raise RuntimeError('Set up Redis To Go first.')

urlparse.uses_netloc.append('redis')
url = urlparse.urlparse(redis_url)
conn = Redis(host=url.hostname, port=url.port, db=0, password=url.password)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

Procfie:

```
web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --log-file -
worker: python -u worker.py
```

Settings.py(This gives me error.)

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings rqworker high default low
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot enqueue the whole view function this way (expects a `request` object whereas you pass a `str`).

Are you trying to achieve some kind of async processing view? Instead you should identify the long processing function and enqueue the job inside the view, more like this:

```
def s3_async_upload(obj):
    obj.save()

def youmaterial(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        newdoc = Youmaterial(docfile=request.FILES['file'], user=request.user)
        # Replace newdoc.save()
        q.enqueue(s3_async_upload, obj=newdoc)
        msg = 'dee'
        # Redirect to the document list after POST
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': msg}))

    else:
        form1 = DocumentForm()

    return render(request, 'mat_upload.html', {'form': form1})

# or with the `@job` decorator, usage: s3_async_upload(obj=newdoc)

@job
def s3_async_upload(obj):
    obj.save()
```

Maybe other settings will be missing, but hope that's help!

Comment: Will try this thing. Thanks